# How do I take in user input in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

This may be kinda dumb but I'm trying to make a purge command but theres always something wrong with it. Can anyone help please?

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('p!purge'):
        numberoftimes = input(int('How many times: '))
        await message.channel.purge(limit=str(numberoftimes))
```

Comment: What is wrong with the command?

Comment: Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 35, in on_message
    numberoftimes = input(int('How many times: '))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'How many times: '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll start with answering your question, then I'll clarify on a better way to create a purge command. To answer your question, there is no need to make an `input()` statement. Rather, this is how you make an input prompt with a Discord bot:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('p!purge'):
        await message.channel.send('How many messages do you want to purge?')

        while True:
            numberoftimes = client.wait_for('message')  # This means, the client is waiting for a message
            if numberoftimes.author == message.author:  # Make sure that the person responding is the person who did the command
                limit = int(numberoftimes.content)  # If its a string, it will be treated as a word. You want to purge a "number" of messages
        await message.channel.purge(limit=limit+1)
```

That's how you would purge messages in a channel. But, the way you are creating this command can be made simpler. You can use the command decorator, which is the "standard" way of doing things:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='p!')

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def purge(ctx, limit):
    limit = int(limit)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=limit + 1)
```

Comment: I got this error code: AttributeError: module 'ctx' has no attribute 'send'

Comment: I changed something in the code portion of the top. Try that. It should work.

Comment: I AM SO SORRY I dont want to be a pain but I got this error message: RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Comment: No problem. I enjoy troubleshooting. I'll try to find the error.

Comment: Have you tried the second method? That should really help. That way, it will be more... proper, I should say.

Comment: Yeah I tried the second method but it says that 'command' is undefined :(

Comment: @NicholasChen That's probably because you haven't imported the commands module. Make sure to add this import statement to the beginning of the code: ```from discord.ext import commands```

Comment: please dont kill me but when I tested it out it didnt do anything

thanks for the info tho! ur a rly good developer (better than me ;-;)

Comment: @NicholasChen I'm not angry. As a developer, I find it cool to help other developers. You said nothing happened, right? Did you get an error at all? Or did nothing just happen at all?

Comment: No messages purged either?

Comment: nvm it worked but it purged like 1000 messages

Comment: also when I do the first one I get `Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 87, in on_message
    if numberoftimes.author == message.author:
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'author'
/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py:340: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'wait_for' was never awaited
  pass`